# R 3.1.0 - What is True Matrix Multiplication and what is is used for?

Tags: r

i need help understanding "true matrix multiplication : x %*% y".

What is it and when it is useful? I've done some testing, but don't get it. Help.

I've tried this:

1) Created this vectors:

```
x <- matrix(1:4, 2,2); y <- matrix(rep(10,4), 2,2)
```

2) Print x:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

3) Print y:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   10
[2,]   10   10
```

4) Print x * y

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   30
[2,]   20   40
```

5) Print x %*% y:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   40   40
[2,]   60   60
```

Help.

Comment: If you want help understanding what matrix multiplication is, this is not the site you are looking for! Try [math.se] or an introductory text on matrix algebra.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematics, namely matrix algebra

Answer (score 2):

`z <- x*y` refers to element-by-element multiplication.  That is, `z[i,j] == x[i,j] * y[i,j]` for each `i` and `j`.  In this case, `x` and `y` must have the same dimensions.

Matrix multiplication is the inner products of the rows of one matrix with the columns of the other.  For `z <- x %*% y`, `x` must have as many rows as `y` has columns.  In that case, `z[i,j]` is the inner product of the `i`th row of `x` with the `j`th column of `y`.

One use is in linear algebra.  If `x` is seen as a linear transformation `F` and `y` is seen as a linear transformation `G`, `x %*% y` is the composite linear transformation `F o G`.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Lundberg. But how do we get in step 5: 40s and 60s? I don't see the logic behind that.